# Optimizing "starts with" comparisons in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, query-optimization

I have a table with 450,000 rows that has a `varchar` column which is of variable length (between 6 and 13 characters, unevenly distributed). I need to join to another table using criteria that says a column in the target table starts with the value of the column of the first table.

In my current test sample, I know that all the matches will be 6 characters, so I'm doing a join using `t1.Digits = left(t2.Number, 6)`, which is very fast (a few seconds to run my large query). My test sample is 10,000 records, though in production the query will need to operate on hundreds of thousands.

I also know that the vast majority of records will always be 6-character matches, but I need to support matching on more, or I'll sometimes get duplicate records returned. The problem is that I've tried all of the following ways of doing this, and each one is much slower than my simpler join on the left six characters. I've never let them run longer than five minutes, but they show no signs of ever terminating:

1. `t1.Digits = left(t2.Number, datalength(t1.Digits))`
2. `charindex(t1.Digits, t2.Number) = 1`
3. Adding a pre-calculated `DigitLength int` column to `t1` and then using `t1.Digits = left(t2.Number, t1.DigitLength)`
4. `t2.Number like t1.Digits + '%'`

Each of the above four solutions achieves what I want theoretically, but runs much too slowly for my purposes.

Even though the values in these columns are numeric, I'm using `varchar` because in many cases there are leading zeroes that need to be preserved. In any case, there ought to be a fast solution even for cases where the data is alphanumeric.

Is anyone aware of a very fast "starts with" logic that would be comparable in performance to my too-simplistic join?

I do have a clustered index on the `t1.Digits` column?

Here's an execution plan running with method #4 above:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ShowPlanXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.0" Build="9.00.5000.00" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan">
  <BatchSequence>
    <Batch>
      <Statements>
        <StmtSimple StatementCompId="1" StatementEstRows="10720" StatementId="1" StatementOptmLevel="FULL" StatementSubTreeCost="7471.7" StatementText="select c.FromNumber, c.ToNumber, d.Destination, d.Digits&#xD;&#xA;from Converting c&#xD;&#xA;--join CASH.CASH.dbo.DestinationLookup d on d.Digits = left(c.FromNumber, 6) &#xD;&#xA;join CASH.CASH.dbo.DestinationLookup d on c.FromNumber like d.Digits + '%' &#xD;&#xA;" StatementType="SELECT">
          <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="false" ANSI_PADDING="false" ANSI_WARNINGS="false" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="false" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="false" />
          <QueryPlan DegreeOfParallelism="1" MemoryGrant="114" CachedPlanSize="99" CompileTime="36" CompileCPU="35" CompileMemory="312">
            <RelOp AvgRowSize="77" EstimateCPU="174.861" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="10720" LogicalOp="Inner Join" NodeId="0" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Nested Loops" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="7471.7">
              <OutputList>
                <ColumnReference Database="[CASH]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Converting]" Alias="[c]" Column="FromNumber" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[CASH]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Converting]" Alias="[c]" Column="ToNumber" />
                <ColumnReference Server="[CASH]" Database="[CASH]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[DestinationLookup]" Alias="[d]" Column="Digits" />
                <ColumnReference Server="[CASH]" Database="[CASH]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[DestinationLookup]" Alias="[d]" Column="Destination" />
              </OutputList>
              <RunTimeInformation>
                <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="10720" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
              </RunTimeInformation>
              <NestedLoops Optimized="false">
                <OuterReferences>
                  <ColumnReference Database="[CASH]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Converting]" Alias="[c]" Column="FromNumber" />
                </OuterReferences>
                <RelOp AvgRowSize="38" EstimateCPU="0.164714" EstimateIO="0.00281532" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="10720" LogicalOp="Sort" NodeId="1" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Sort" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.340338">
                  <OutputList>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[CASH]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Converting]" Alias="[c]" Column="FromNumber" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[CASH]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Converting]" Alias="[c]" Column="ToNumber" />
                  </OutputList>
                  <MemoryFractions Input="1" Output="1" />
                  <RunTimeInformation>
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRebinds="1" ActualRewinds="0" ActualRows="10720" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                  </RunTimeInformation>
                  <Sort Distinct="false">
                    <OrderBy>
                      <OrderByColumn Ascending="true">
                        <ColumnReference Database="[CASH]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Converting]" Alias="[c]" Column="FromNumber" />
                      </OrderByColumn>
                    </OrderBy>
                    <RelOp AvgRowSize="38" EstimateCPU="0.00296763" EstimateIO="0.126907" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="10720" LogicalOp="Table Scan" NodeId="2" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Table Scan" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.129875">
                      <OutputList>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[CASH]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Converting]" Alias="[c]" Column="FromNumber" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[CASH]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Converting]" Alias="[c]" Column="ToNumber" />
                      </OutputList>
                      <RunTimeInformation>
                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="10720" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                      </RunTimeInformation>
                      <TableScan Ordered="false" ForcedIndex="false" NoExpandHint="false">
                        <DefinedValues>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[CASH]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Converting]" Alias="[c]" Column="FromNumber" />
                          </DefinedValue>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[CASH]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Converting]" Alias="[c]" Column="ToNumber" />
                          </DefinedValue>
                        </DefinedValues>
                        <Object Database="[CASH]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Converting]" Alias="[c]" />
                      </TableScan>
                    </RelOp>
                  </Sort>
                </RelOp>
                <RelOp AvgRowSize="48" EstimateCPU="0.00290986" EstimateIO="0.01" EstimateRebinds="1390" EstimateRewinds="9329" EstimateRows="15609.2" LogicalOp="Lazy Spool" NodeId="3" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Table Spool" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="7296.5">
                  <OutputList>
                    <ColumnReference Server="[CASH]" Database="[CASH]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[DestinationLookup]" Alias="[d]" Column="Digits" />
                    <ColumnReference Server="[CASH]" Database="[CASH]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[DestinationLookup]" Alias="[d]" Column="Destination" />
                  </OutputList>
                  <RunTimeInformation>
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRebinds="1391" ActualRewinds="9329" ActualRows="10720" ActualEndOfScans="10720" ActualExecutions="10720" />
                  </RunTimeInformation>
                  <Spool>
                    <RelOp AvgRowSize="48" EstimateCPU="5.21308" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="1390" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="15609.2" LogicalOp="Compute Scalar" NodeId="4" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Compute Scalar" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="7251.4">
                      <OutputList>
                        <ColumnReference Server="[CASH]" Database="[CASH]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[DestinationLookup]" Alias="[d]" Column="Digits" />
                        <ColumnReference Server="[CASH]" Database="[CASH]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[DestinationLookup]" Alias="[d]" Column="Destination" />
                      </OutputList>
                      <ComputeScalar>
                        <DefinedValues>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Server="[CASH]" Database="[CASH]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[DestinationLookup]" Alias="[d]" Column="Digits" />
                            <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[CASH].[CASH].[dbo].[DestinationLookup].[Digits] as [d].[Digits]">
                              <Identifier>
                                <ColumnReference Server="[CASH]" Database="[CASH]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[DestinationLookup]" Alias="[d]" Column="Digits" />
                              </Identifier>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </DefinedValue>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Server="[CASH]" Database="[CASH]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[DestinationLookup]" Alias="[d]" Column="Destination" />
                            <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[CASH].[CASH].[dbo].[DestinationLookup].[Destination] as [d].[Destination]">
                              <Identifier>
                                <ColumnReference Server="[CASH]" Database="[CASH]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[DestinationLookup]" Alias="[d]" Column="Destination" />
                              </Identifier>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </DefinedValue>
                        </DefinedValues>
                        <RelOp AvgRowSize="48" EstimateCPU="5.21308" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="1390" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="15609.2" LogicalOp="Remote Query" NodeId="5" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Remote Query" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="7251.4">
                          <OutputList>
                            <ColumnReference Server="[CASH]" Database="[CASH]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[DestinationLookup]" Alias="[d]" Column="Digits" />
                            <ColumnReference Server="[CASH]" Database="[CASH]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[DestinationLookup]" Alias="[d]" Column="Destination" />
                          </OutputList>
                          <RunTimeInformation>
                            <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRebinds="1391" ActualRewinds="0" ActualRows="1391" ActualEndOfScans="1391" ActualExecutions="1391" />
                          </RunTimeInformation>
                          <RemoteQuery RemoteSource="CASH" RemoteQuery="SELECT &quot;Tbl1004&quot;.&quot;Digits&quot; &quot;Col1021&quot;,&quot;Tbl1004&quot;.&quot;Destination&quot; &quot;Col1022&quot; FROM &quot;CASH&quot;.&quot;dbo&quot;.&quot;DestinationLookup&quot; &quot;Tbl1004&quot; WHERE ? like &quot;Tbl1004&quot;.&quot;Digits&quot;+'%'" />
                        </RelOp>
                      </ComputeScalar>
                    </RelOp>
                  </Spool>
                </RelOp>
              </NestedLoops>
            </RelOp>
          </QueryPlan>
        </StmtSimple>
      </Statements>
    </Batch>
  </BatchSequence>
</ShowPlanXML>
```

And here's the plan when joining with a simple left(t2.Number, 6):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ShowPlanXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.0" Build="9.00.5000.00" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan">
  <BatchSequence>
    <Batch>
      <Statements>
        <StmtSimple StatementCompId="1" StatementEstRows="10720" StatementId="1" StatementOptmLevel="FULL" StatementSubTreeCost="15.1845" StatementText="select c.FromNumber, c.ToNumber, d.Destination, d.Digits&#xD;&#xA;from Converting c&#xD;&#xA;join CASH.CASH.dbo.DestinationLookup d on d.Digits = left(c.FromNumber, 6) " StatementType="SELECT">
          <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="false" ANSI_PADDING="false" ANSI_WARNINGS="false" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="false" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="false" />
          <QueryPlan DegreeOfParallelism="1" CachedPlanSize="105" CompileTime="60" CompileCPU="58" CompileMemory="360">
            <RelOp AvgRowSize="77" EstimateCPU="0.0448096" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="10720" LogicalOp="Inner Join" NodeId="0" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Nested Loops" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="15.1845">
              <OutputList>
                <ColumnReference Database="[CASH]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Converting]" Alias="[c]" Column="FromNumber" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[CASH]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Converting]" Alias="[c]" Column="ToNumber" />
                <ColumnReference Server="[CASH]" Database="[CASH]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[DestinationLookup]" Alias="[d]" Column="Digits" />
                <ColumnReference Server="[CASH]" Database="[CASH]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[DestinationLookup]" Alias="[d]" Column="Destination" />
              </OutputList>
              <RunTimeInformation>
                <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="10720" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
              </RunTimeInformation>
              <NestedLoops Optimized="false">
                <OuterReferences>
                  <ColumnReference Column="Expr1005" />
                </OuterReferences>
                <RelOp AvgRowSize="43" EstimateCPU="0.001072" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="10720" LogicalOp="Compute Scalar" NodeId="1" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Compute Scalar" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.13985">
                  <OutputList>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[CASH]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Converting]" Alias="[c]" Column="FromNumber" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[CASH]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Converting]" Alias="[c]" Column="ToNumber" />
                    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1005" />
                  </OutputList>
                  <ComputeScalar>
                    <DefinedValues>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Column="Expr1005" />
                        <ScalarOperator ScalarString="substring([CASH].[dbo].[Converting].[FromNumber] as [c].[FromNumber],(1),(6))">
                          <Intrinsic FunctionName="substring">
                            <ScalarOperator>
                              <Identifier>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[CASH]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Converting]" Alias="[c]" Column="FromNumber" />
                              </Identifier>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                            <ScalarOperator>
                              <Const ConstValue="(1)" />
                            </ScalarOperator>
                            <ScalarOperator>
                              <Const ConstValue="(6)" />
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </Intrinsic>
                        </ScalarOperator>
                      </DefinedValue>
                    </DefinedValues>
                    <RelOp AvgRowSize="38" EstimateCPU="0.011949" EstimateIO="0.126829" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="10720" LogicalOp="Table Scan" NodeId="2" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Table Scan" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.138778">
                      <OutputList>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[CASH]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Converting]" Alias="[c]" Column="FromNumber" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[CASH]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Converting]" Alias="[c]" Column="ToNumber" />
                      </OutputList>
                      <RunTimeInformation>
                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="10720" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                      </RunTimeInformation>
                      <TableScan Ordered="false" ForcedIndex="false" NoExpandHint="false">
                        <DefinedValues>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[CASH]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Converting]" Alias="[c]" Column="FromNumber" />
                          </DefinedValue>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[CASH]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Converting]" Alias="[c]" Column="ToNumber" />
                          </DefinedValue>
                        </DefinedValues>
                        <Object Database="[CASH]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Converting]" Alias="[c]" />
                      </TableScan>
                    </RelOp>
                  </ComputeScalar>
                </RelOp>
                <RelOp AvgRowSize="48" EstimateCPU="0.000258212" EstimateIO="0.003125" EstimateRebinds="10580.9" EstimateRewinds="138.124" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Lazy Spool" NodeId="6" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Index Spool" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="14.9998">
                  <OutputList>
                    <ColumnReference Server="[CASH]" Database="[CASH]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[DestinationLookup]" Alias="[d]" Column="Digits" />
                    <ColumnReference Server="[CASH]" Database="[CASH]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[DestinationLookup]" Alias="[d]" Column="Destination" />
                  </OutputList>
                  <RunTimeInformation>
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRebinds="830" ActualRewinds="9890" ActualRows="10720" ActualEndOfScans="0" ActualExecutions="10720" />
                  </RunTimeInformation>
                  <Spool>
                    <SeekPredicate>
                      <Prefix ScanType="EQ">
                        <RangeColumns>
                          <ColumnReference Column="Expr1005" />
                        </RangeColumns>
                        <RangeExpressions>
                          <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[Expr1005]">
                            <Identifier>
                              <ColumnReference Column="Expr1005" />
                            </Identifier>
                          </ScalarOperator>
                        </RangeExpressions>
                      </Prefix>
                    </SeekPredicate>
                    <RelOp AvgRowSize="48" EstimateCPU="0.0103333" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="1180" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Compute Scalar" NodeId="7" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Compute Scalar" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="12.2037">
                      <OutputList>
                        <ColumnReference Server="[CASH]" Database="[CASH]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[DestinationLookup]" Alias="[d]" Column="Digits" />
                        <ColumnReference Server="[CASH]" Database="[CASH]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[DestinationLookup]" Alias="[d]" Column="Destination" />
                      </OutputList>
                      <ComputeScalar>
                        <DefinedValues>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Server="[CASH]" Database="[CASH]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[DestinationLookup]" Alias="[d]" Column="Digits" />
                            <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[CASH].[CASH].[dbo].[DestinationLookup].[Digits] as [d].[Digits]">
                              <Identifier>
                                <ColumnReference Server="[CASH]" Database="[CASH]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[DestinationLookup]" Alias="[d]" Column="Digits" />
                              </Identifier>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </DefinedValue>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Server="[CASH]" Database="[CASH]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[DestinationLookup]" Alias="[d]" Column="Destination" />
                            <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[CASH].[CASH].[dbo].[DestinationLookup].[Destination] as [d].[Destination]">
                              <Identifier>
                                <ColumnReference Server="[CASH]" Database="[CASH]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[DestinationLookup]" Alias="[d]" Column="Destination" />
                              </Identifier>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </DefinedValue>
                        </DefinedValues>
                        <RelOp AvgRowSize="48" EstimateCPU="0.0103333" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="1180" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Remote Query" NodeId="8" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Remote Query" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="12.2037">
                          <OutputList>
                            <ColumnReference Server="[CASH]" Database="[CASH]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[DestinationLookup]" Alias="[d]" Column="Digits" />
                            <ColumnReference Server="[CASH]" Database="[CASH]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[DestinationLookup]" Alias="[d]" Column="Destination" />
                          </OutputList>
                          <RunTimeInformation>
                            <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRebinds="456" ActualRewinds="0" ActualRows="456" ActualEndOfScans="0" ActualExecutions="456" />
                          </RunTimeInformation>
                          <RemoteQuery RemoteSource="CASH" RemoteQuery="SELECT &quot;Tbl1004&quot;.&quot;Digits&quot; &quot;Col1015&quot;,&quot;Tbl1004&quot;.&quot;Destination&quot; &quot;Col1016&quot; FROM &quot;CASH&quot;.&quot;dbo&quot;.&quot;DestinationLookup&quot; &quot;Tbl1004&quot; WHERE &quot;Tbl1004&quot;.&quot;Digits&quot;=?" />
                        </RelOp>
                      </ComputeScalar>
                    </RelOp>
                  </Spool>
                </RelOp>
              </NestedLoops>
            </RelOp>
          </QueryPlan>
        </StmtSimple>
      </Statements>
    </Batch>
  </BatchSequence>
</ShowPlanXML>
```

**UPDATE:** I've been unable to find an ideal solution, but I have discovered a next-best thing.  It seems that a trivially simple query on these two tables using "like" completes in about five seconds.  So rather than try to cram the join into my monster query, where it never completes, I've used it to create a temporary lookup table, which my monster query then uses.  In all, the big query completes in nine seconds now, and I have support for variable length strings in my varchar join.

Another thing that helped speed this up was changing the fill factor for the column in t1 from 80 to 100.  This fill factor is ideal for the table because it's a static reference table that only changes once a year.

Comment: Functions such as `LIKE` aren't sargable, meaning normal indices will be ignored.  I really don't think there is a good way to do what you're attempting.  Why can't you just store the appropriate value in your t2 table?

Comment: Who told you that? Only the leading wildcard kills index use, not the LIKE itself. Eg, `WHERE col LIKE 'x%'` will use an index on col if one exists.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  Unfortunately, my t2 table doesn't have static contents. It's used for processing new incoming records of which there will be millions per month.  Putting the appropriate value in it is essentially what I'm trying to do with this join.

Comment: @dean, thanks for demonstrating that "like" is the fastest of these four options.  I still need something faster, but it's good to know anyway.

Comment: Show us the actual execution plans then, and thx for the upvote :)

Comment: @dean, I've included the execution plans for a simplified version of my query, run both ways. The first one (#4 on the list), took several minutes to complete, whereas the second (simple join using the six leftmost characters) completed in less than one second.

Comment: Thanks. I see that DestinationLookup table is on a linked server and that the estimates for the `LIKE` query are totally wrong, so yes, in that case the second really could behave better.

Answer (score 2):

The most performant solution of those four is the fourth one.

Let's set up the test environment:

```
create table #t1 (digits varchar(10), filler char(5000) default(''))
create table #t2 (number varchar(10), filler char(5000) default(''))
go

insert #t1 (digits) values
('123'),('234'),('345'),('456'),('567')

insert #t2 (number) values
('1234'),('234'),('345689'),('45'),('567890')
go

create index ix_t2 on #t2(number);
go
```

Now, let's execute four semantically identical queries, but with Query --> Include Actual Execution Plan enabled, and also with `SET STATISTICS IO ON`:

```
-- 1
select *
from #t1
inner join #t2
on #t1.digits = left(#t2.number, datalength(#t1.digits))

-- 2
select *
from #t1
inner join #t2
on charindex(#t1.Digits, #t2.Number) = 1

-- 3
select *
from #t1
inner join #t2
on charindex(#t1.digits, #t2.number) = 1

-- 4
select *
from #t1
inner join #t2
on #t2.number like #t1.digits + '%'
```

As you can see, execution plans for 1, 2 & 3 include the table scan operators on both tables (including an additional Compute Scalar operator for the first one), but the fourth query does index seek on our index on #t2. Moreover, if you check the output of statistics io, you'll see the logical reads measure on #t2 (the table with the index) for the 1, 2 & 3 as 25, but for the fourth one as only 14 (of course, with more rows, the numbers go high up).

Answer (score 1):

Build an index on `table1.digits`.  Then try the following:

```
select t2.*, t1.<whatever>
from table1 t2 cross apply
     (select top 1 <whatever>
      from table1 t1
      where t1.digits <= t2.number
      order by t1.digits desc
     ) t1;
```

SQL Server is sometimes better at optimizing "apply" queries than regular joins.  In this case, it might spot that the index is useful both for the `where` and `order by` and proceed efficiently.  (I also think the same would apply to a correlated subquery.)

Comment: CROSS APPLY (CA) and correlated subqueries (CS) are different beasts altogether. You can't use the CS as a query source, to start with. CA causes the subquery to be executed once for each row of the outer query, which could be devastating for performance, it's actually a cursor by another name. Joins and CAs are optimized very differently, because it's two semantically different expressions. Your statement that "SQL Server is sometimes better at optimizing "apply" queries than regular joins" is true in cases when cursors are faster than set-based solutions.

Comment: @dean . . . I'm not exactly sure what your point is.  There are cases where `cross apply` performance is better than alternatives.  Here is an example: http://explainextended.com/2009/07/16/inner-join-vs-cross-apply/.  In this case, a single execution per row that is essentially an index scan could be more efficient than other methods.

Comment: Sure, there are cases when a cursor is faster than a set-based solution, I don't argue with that. But my point was then you're comparing apples and oranges with CA vs CS comparison.

Comment: @Dean . . . There are comparisons of `CROSS APPLY`/cursor performance (http://shannonlowder.com/2012/01/improve-performance-by-replacing-cursors/).  You seem to have some knowledge of databases, but cursors and set-based operations are implemented *very* differently in the database.  They may be applied in some cases to similar problems, but that does not mean that they are doing the same thing.  For instance, SQL Server can use a parallel query plan for apply operations (when appropriate) but cursors inherently introduce serial processing.

Comment: We're talking RBAR here, one way or another. Is there a way to move the discussion away from the comments? I'm still a rookie here :)